# Interpret P-value in ANOVA table and Parameter Table

Tags: fitting

I wonder how different between P-value in these 2 tables since they are not equal. I have check on Mathematica document. There is no information about these 2 tables in comparison.[image]

Comment: It might be informative to re-fit the same model with a different ordering of the terms. As I recall the ANOVA table depends on order but looking at the parameter table I would expect that it would not. I would also expect that you could remove everything but the $x y$ and $x^2 y^2$ terms and not reduce the model's fit much.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could supply the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only P-value that should match is the last term ($x^2 y^2$) but it doesn't in your case because of numerical precision issues (certainly in part because of the orders of magnitude differences in the estimates of the coefficients).  Maybe if you rationalized the data, that last term's P-value would match.

(While the P-value should match for the $x^2 y^2$ term, note that the square of the t-statistic in the "ParameterTable" for $x^2 y^2$ is the value of the F-statistic in the "ANOVATable".  (Again, the P-value should match but doesn't because of numerical  precision issues with the algorithm applied to this set of data.  If you are able to post the data, this could be verified.)

The reason the other P-values don't match the corresponding terms is that the "ANOVATable" gives you P-values based on "sequential sums of squares" (or Type I sums of squares in SAS lingo) which is what @eyorble mentioned.  This means that the P-value for `x` in the "ANOVATable" is that of the model only containing `x`. The P-value for `y` in that table is that of the effect of adding `y` to the model that contains `x`.

Here is an example without numerical precision issues.  Reordering the terms will give different P-values because each line (except the last) is essentially testing a different hypothesis.

```
SeedRandom[12345];
data = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, z, 1.2 x - 3.4 y + 10 z + RandomReal[10]}, {x, 
     RandomReal[10, 3]}, {y, RandomReal[10, 3]}, {z, 
     RandomReal[10, 3]}], 2];

(* Order:  x y z *)
LinearModelFit[data, {x, y, z}, {x, y, z}]["ANOVATable"]
```

[image: "ANOVATable" for the order x y z]

```
(* Order: y x z *)
LinearModelFit[data, {y, x, z}, {x, y, z}]["ANOVATable"]
```

[image: "ANOVATable" for the order y x z]

Now for the "ParameterTable":

```
LinearModelFit[data, {x, y, z}, {x, y, z}]["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Parameter table]

Note that the P-values for `z` match in the "ANOVATable" and "ParameterTable".