# P-Values For LinearModelFit Changing Due To Ordering Of Features

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

The arbitrary ordering in a linear model of the independent variables should not impact the p-values for the coefficients of said model.

However that is exactly what is happening here

```
a = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100];
b = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100];
c = Table[1 + a[[i]] + b[[i]] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], {i, 1, 
100}];

LinearModelFit[
Table[{a[[i]], b[[i]]}, {i, 1, 100}] -> c, {1, x, y}, {x, y}]["ANOVATable"]

LinearModelFit[
Table[{b[[i]], a[[i]]}, {i, 1, 100}] -> c, {1, x, y}, {x, 
 y}]["ANOVATable"]
```

Any help in explaining this and if needed, correcting this would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275272/interpret-p-value-in-anova-table-and-parameter-table/275283#275283.

Comment: A good explanation of Type II and Type III sums of squares is found at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/643178/how-does-type-ii-vs-type-iii-anova-work-when-there-are-more-than-two-categorical.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no correction needed (although you might want to do something different). *Mathematica* provides Type I Sums of Squares (also called Sequential Sums of Squares) and the order definitely matters.

The way you've labeled things for the first `LinearModelFit` you are getting the sum of squares for `x` (not accounting for `y`) and the sum of squares for `y` after accounting for `x`.  More generally sequential sums of squares are "adjusted for terms preceding it and unadjusted for terms following it".

There are Types I, II, III, and IV sums of squares which essentially test different hypotheses.  So knowing what hypothesis you want to test is essential.  A Google-search on any of those terms should given you the associated definitions.